# Lenovo X131e Chromebook Ubuntu installation

Tags: system-installation, google-chrome, lenovo, chromebook

Has anyone been able to successfully install Ubuntu on a Lenovo X131e Chromebook?  I'm able to run the scripts and install it but after it completes the install I cannot get Ubuntu to start, it just starts in Chrome.  It partitions the SSD for sure because I can see it in the Chrome OS.  Any ideas on how to get it to start or a proper way to install?

Comment: I recommend fully installing Ubuntu and wiping ChromeOS from your system. I have a _very_ detailed answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/930272/690724) on how to do it. AFAIK, it works on all Chromebooks. If your device isn't listed, just try to find another BIOS you can flash. Once you do that, you can install nearly any OS you want. I've almost gotten Windows 10 installed but I decided Linux was better, in the long run, on a Chromebook.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want the LTS (long term support) version of ubuntu.
There is a tool developed for this. It's called [crouton](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton).
Since chromeOS is based on linux you'll be able to switch with a simple keyboard shortcut (if you want you can also make it a more traditional dualboot (you'll want [this script](http://chromeos-cr48.blogspot.fr/) if you want to do that) but this is imho better.

First things first: make a backup of all the files you want to save that are not in the cloud (because they WILL be lost).

2) Press and hold the Esc and Refresh keys together, then press the Power button (while still holding the other two keys). This will reboot your Chromebook into Recovery Mode.

3) When you get the yellow screen with the exclamation mark hit ctrl + d (This will bring up a prompt asking if you want to turn on Developer Mode.) Press enter (this will take about 15 to 20 min. You'll get a screen with a red exclamation mark but leave it be until it reboots into chromeOS).

4) [Download crouton](http://goo.gl/fd3zc)

5) press ctrl + alt + T and you'll get a terminal (linux uses the same shortcuts)

6) type "shell" (without the quotation marks) to get a ubuntu shell

7) type this command

```
sudo sh -e ~/Downloads/crouton -t xfce
```

(if you have a touch screen you'll want to change that to include the touch functions)

```
sudo sh -e ~/Downloads/crouton -t touch,xfce
```

if you want the unity desktop then change xfce for unity

if you want another release then run this to give you a list of the recognized releases and which distros they belong to.

```
sh -e ~/Downloads/crouton -r list
```

8) Let it run. (when it's done it'll ask you for a new username and password)

9) run this command to start your new environment.

```
sudo startxfce4
```

10) Now, you can switch back and forth between Chrome OS and Ubuntu using Ctrl+Alt+Shift+Back and Ctrl+Alt+Shift+Forward (if you're on an ARM-based Chromebook) or Ctrl+Alt+Back and Ctrl+Alt+Forward (If you're on an Intel-based Chromebook). In the latter case, you will also need to press Ctrl+Alt+Refresh after pressing Ctrl+Alt+Forward to bring up the desktop. To exit the Linux desktop, just log out of it like you would on a normal PC—you'll close it completely and go back to Chrome OS (after which you can run sudo startxfce4 again to go back).

if you experience problems the crouton link on the top redirects you to the official crouton page including a troubleshooting page