# How to install ubuntu on a lenovo thinkpad x131e

Tags: system-installation

I need help trying to install ubuntu on my laptop but im not able to run the exe file becuase its running on a chrome os. I could really use some help on this.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to install Ubuntu on a school chromebook.

You can't, unless you put it in dev mode first. Also, .exe's don't run on ChromeOS.

Instructions on dev mode and crouton can be found on [chromium.org](https://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/developer-information-for-chrome-os-devices/lenovo-thinkpad-x131e-chromebook).

https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton

(It'll wipe your machine)

Comment: i already know that you cant run exe files on chromeOS it says it in the question and its already in developer mode and i tried doing the crouton  but it didn't really work out but i will try again thanks for your help

Comment: @tanksenpai This is a better thread: http://askubuntu.com/questions/355110/lenovo-x131e-chromebook-ubuntu-installation. By any chance, is this on a school chromebook?

Comment: i bought it online because i needed a computer to test stuff on.